# Map a Stored Procedure to Entity Framework with MergeOption

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there a way to map a stored procedure to Entity Framework in such a way that the ExecuteFunction uses the MergeOption parameter with the NoTracking option?

Answer (score 0):

You could update the T4 template file to add "MergeOption.NoTracking" as the 2nd parameters. Then just R-Click on the .edmx and select "Run Custom Tool".

This is a quick workaround but I would also like to know a more long term solution.  If this is the only solution, can the default T4 templates be updated so that this is automatic with new EntityModels and were are they stored.

{EnitityModel}.Context.tt
Line 290:

```
"return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction{0}(\"{1}\", MergeOption.NoTracking{2});",
```

I was setting the following in my Repository constructor, but the MergeOption appears to be cleaner

```
context = new Entities();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```